# unexpected result when moving from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the first fragment, there are some textviews. For example, a, b and c.

When I click a ,it will go to another fragment and show a for apple.
However, when I go back to the first fragment and click b, it still show a for apple. I need to go back to first fragment and click b again and then it will show the correct word.

```
public class location extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("gateway");
    LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.locationlayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    params.setMargins(20,10,10,10);


    Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
    String ble_num=intent.getStringExtra("num");
    int number=Integer.parseInt(ble_num);
    final String ble_id[]=new String[number];
    final String alias[]=new String[number];
    final String serial_number[]=new String[number];
    final TextView[] textView= new TextView[number];

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        ble_id[i]=sharedPreferences.getString("ble_id"+i,"123");
        alias[i]=sharedPreferences.getString("alias"+i,"123");
        serial_number[i]=sharedPreferences.getString("serial_number"+i,"123");
    }


        for (int j=0; j<number; j++){
            textView[j]= new TextView(getActivity());
            textView[j].setText("location: "+alias[j]+"\n"+"id: "+ble_id[j]+", serial number: "+serial_number[j]);
            textView[j].setId(j);
            textView[j].setLayoutParams(params);
            linearLayout.addView(textView[j]);

            final int finalJ = j;
            textView[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Response.Listener<String> ResponseListener= new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try{

                                JSONObject jsonRespon = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray array=jsonRespon.getJSONArray("result");

                                String num=jsonRespon.getString("num");
                                int number=Integer.parseInt(num);
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("slave_num",num).commit();

                                String slave_id[]=new String[number];
                                String slave_alias[]=new String[number];

                                for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
                                    JSONObject item= array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    slave_id[i]=item.getString("slave_id");
                                    slave_alias[i]=item.getString("slave_alias");

                                    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("slave_id"+i,slave_id[i]).putString("slave_alias"+i,slave_alias[i])
                                            .commit();
                                }

                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    slave slave = new slave(ble_id[finalJ], ResponseListener);
                    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    queue.add(slave);

                    Fragment fragment = new slavepage();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_drawer, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }






}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
}
}
```

This is the first fragment.

```
public class slavepage extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("slave");

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.slavelayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    params.setMargins(20, 10, 10, 10);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String slave_num = sharedPreferences.getString("slave_num", "");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(slave_num);
    String slave_id[]=new String[number];
    String slave_alias[]=new String[number];
    TextView[] textViews=new TextView[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        slave_id[i]=sharedPreferences.getString("slave_id"+i,"123");
        slave_alias[i]=sharedPreferences.getString("slave_alias"+i,"123");
    }

    for (int j=0;j<number;j++){
        textViews[j]= new TextView(getActivity());
        textViews[j].setText("alias: "+slave_alias[j]+"\n"+"id: "+slave_id[j]);
        textViews[j].setId(j);
        textViews[j].setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(textViews[j]);
    }
    }
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle
        savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.slave, container, false);
}
}
```

This is the second fragment.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you using fragments for tabbed activity?

Comment: no, it is drawer activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragment = new slavepage();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_drawer, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Your above code run immediately after

```
queue.add(slave);
```

Not inside network block function

Comment: Thanks. I put the code in the listener and the problem is solved

Comment: Hi. If the answer solve your problem. Please mark it as true question for help other people when searching.